# Formatting Erlang terms without lists-to-strings translation

Tags: erlang

How do I format Erlang terms without detecting lists of printable character codes? E.g. instead of

```
1> io:format("foo=~p~n", [[50]]). 
foo="2"
```

I want to get `foo=[50]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of R16B](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B.readme), you can use the `l` (small letter ell) modifier to the `~p` format directive to disable string detection:

```
1> io:format("~p~n", [[10]]).
"\n"
ok
2> io:format("~lp~n", [[10]]).
[10]
ok
```

This means that you can still get the line breaks and depth limitation that `~p` offers as opposed to `~w`.

Answer (score 4):

if you use "~w" rather than "~p" it should give you the list without changing it into a string:

```
io:format("foo=~w~n", [[50]]).
```

see the documentatin for it here:

http://erldocs.com/R14B/stdlib/io.html?i=3&search=io:#format/1

Answer (score 1):

Use flag `~w` in `io:format`.

```
1> io:format("foo=~w~n", [[50]]). 
foo=[50]
```